# AndEngine Particle Collision

Tags: sprite, physics, andengine, collision, particles

I'm new to AndEngine, and after making a super simple program of my own, I moved on to the physics extension.

I've been toying around with the example's source code for a while, but I cannot figure out how to implement collision detection between particle systems, or even better, between particle systems and sprites.

Does anyone have any ideas? At least point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience there is no way to check a collision between a sprite and a particle system, simply because AndEngine will not let you do Sprite.collidesWith(particleSystem);

I would guess you are trying to do something like see if your character walks onto the fire("particleSystem"), then the character would take some damage?
How I would personally solve this problem would be to place a Rectangle Shape around where you would expect the particleSystem to be, and then check the collision between your sprite and the rectangle

Hope this helps!